# Installing PyHook python 3.7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, package, pyhook

I’ve been trying to pip install pyHook for about 3 hours and tried every method that I can possibly think of or find but I can’t seem to get it to work. I get the error:

Requirement ‘pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl’ looks like a filename,but file does not exist. Than it says pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Head over to [this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
2. Then find `pyhook` and install `pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`.
3. Go to `cmd` and type `pip install` followed by the path of your pyhook file. For example:

   `C:\\user\download\pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`

Comment: the most recent version from 'this link' is not supported by python activestate 3.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have python3:

```
pip3 install pyHook
```

This should work.

You're also probably on a 64 bit Computer, so in the original wheel method, install the one with the `_amd64` suffix.

Comment: it does not work. pip and pip3 cannot find. tested on windows7 & 8.1 both 64bit, python 64bit (_amd64). I've tested lover and upper cases. python activestate 3.8.0

Comment: Does not work. Tried using `pip 21.0.1` (Python 3.7.9).

Answer (score 0):

If one is using Windows, for installing [`pyHook`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook), download the file related with your system version (32/64) from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook).

Note that for [whl files](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html) one may need to install the [`wheel`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html) package, as

```
pip install wheel
```

And then

```
pip install file_name.whl
```